# How can I automatically start cron in a Docker container that is running PHP?

Tags: php, linux, docker, cron

I'm trying to run some PHP scripts automatically and want to have cron running once the container starts. Below is my current Dockerfile but upon running the `docker-compose up -d` command, the PHP container crashes immediately and I get the errors `Cannot start service composer: Cannot link to a non running container` and `Cannot start service apache: Cannot link to a non running container` which makes sense, because the PHP container already crashed. I've also tried `CMD ["cron", "-f"]` in place of `CMD cron start && tail -f /var/log/cron.log` and all the containers run, and the test job is executed, but I get a 
503 service unavailable error when trying to access the app. From what I've read this is because cron is running in the foreground and blocking PHP.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.4.2-fpm-buster

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
        freetds-bin \
        freetds-dev \
        freetds-common \
        libct4 \
        libsybdb5 \
        tdsodbc \
        libfreetype6-dev \
        libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
        libmcrypt-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libldap2-dev \
        libpq-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
        libc-client-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        zip \
        cron

RUN ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsybdb.a /usr/lib/
RUN ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpq-fe.h /usr/lib/

RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql pdo_dblib pdo_pgsql gd zip

RUN apt-get install unixodbc unixodbc-dev -y \
 && docker-php-ext-configure pdo_odbc --with-pdo-odbc=unixODBC,/usr \
 && docker-php-ext-install pdo_odbc

COPY ./freetds.conf /etc/freetds/freetds.conf
COPY ./odbc.ini /etc/odbc.ini
COPY ./odbcinst.ini /etc/odbcinst.ini
COPY ./php.ini /usr/local/etc/php

# Install Composer
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer

RUN mkdir /var/www/html/files && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/files && chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/files
RUN mkdir /var/www/html/exports && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/exports && chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/exports
RUN mkdir /var/www/html/scripts && chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/scripts && chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/scripts

# copying cronjobs, a file I created with a test cronjob to /etc
COPY ./cronjobs /etc
# using the cronjobs file I created as the crontab
RUN crontab /etc/cronjobs

CMD cron start && tail -f /var/log/cron.log

EXPOSE 9000
```

**docker-compose.yml** (some info redacted ... the xxx parts)

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  php:
    build: './php/'
    links:
      - 'mysql'
    network_mode: "bridge"
    ports:
      - "xxxx:9000"
    volumes:
      - ./www/:/var/www/html/
      - files:/var/www/html/files
  apache:
    build: './apache/'
    depends_on:
      - php
    links:
      - 'php'
    network_mode: "bridge"
    ports:
      - "xxxx:80"
    volumes:
      - ./www/:/var/www/html/
      - files:/var/www/html/files
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    command: --init-file /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'xxx'
      MYSQL_USER: 'xxx'
      MYSQL_PASS: 'xxx'
    ports:
      - "xxxx:3306"
    network_mode: "bridge"
    volumes:
      - data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./mysql/init:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
  phpmyadmin:
    depends_on: 
      - mysql
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: mysql
      PMA_PORT: 3306
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    links:
      - mysql
    network_mode: "bridge"
    ports:
      - "xxxx:80"
  composer:
    container_name: composer
    depends_on:
      - php
    links:
      - 'php'
    image: composer
    network_mode: "bridge"
    volumes:
      - ./www:/var/www/html/
    command: composer install --ignore-platform-reqs && composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet
networks:
  default:
    external:
      name: bridge
volumes:
  data:
  files:
```

**cronjobs file**

```
# Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
#
# Each task to run has to be defined through a single line
# indicating with different fields when the task will be run
# and what command to run for the task
#
# To define the time you can provide concrete values for
# minute (m), hour (h), day of month (dom), month (mon),
# and day of week (dow) or use '*' in these fields (for 'any').
#
# Notice that tasks will be started based on the cron's system
# daemon's notion of time and timezones.
#
# Output of the crontab jobs (including errors) is sent through
# email to the user the crontab file belongs to (unless redirected).
#
# For example, you can run a backup of all your user accounts
# at 5 a.m every week with:
# 0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#
# For more information see the manual pages of crontab(5) and cron(8)
#
# m h  dom mon dow   command

42 22 * * * /usr/local/bin/php /var/www/html/scripts/test.php
```